# Concatenating string and integers in pandas dataframe(based on conditions)

Tags: pandas

In my dataframe I have 2 columns:

1. Country index(For example SK)
2. id_number(usually 8 digit,for example:98341852)

I want to concatenate them and it's easy:

```
sk_df['id'] = sk_df['country index'].str.cat(sk_df['id_number'].values.astype(str))
```

But some of rows in column `id_number` has number of digits less than 8. In this case I want to add zeros as separator between Country index and `id_number`(for example, if length of `id_number` is 6 I want to add 8-6 = 2 zeros between variables: `SK00813841`. If `id_number` length is 7,than add 1 zero etc)

I tried this:

```
def indexing(row):
    if row['id_number'].astype(str).str.len() == 8:
        return row['country index'].str.cat(row['id_number'].values.astype(str))
    else:
        sep_mult = 8 - row['id_number'].astype(str).str.len()
        return row['country index'].str.cat(row['id_number'].values.astype(str),sep = '0'*sep_mult)



sk_df['id'] = sk_df.apply(lambda row: indexing(row),axis = 1)
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

Use `.zfill()`:

```
sk_df['id'] = sk_df['country index'] + sk_df['id_number'].astype(str).str.zfill(8)
```